# How to add slash after autocomplete for symbolic link in Mac os Terminal?

Tags: macos, autocomplete, terminal

I have a problem, after

```
ln -s point1 point2
```

When I try `point1` and put "TAB" button - I need adding "/" to autocomplete, if this symlink point to directory. I use Mac OS terminal.

Is it possible? Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know that depends on the autocompletion of the shell you are using.

If you are using Bash (which you probably are if you did not change your shell) look [at the answer to this question](https://superuser.com/questions/271626/bash-autocomplete-on-symlink-to-directory-complete-to-whole-directory-including)